# 2005 Chevrolet Express 3500: Help Identifying this part

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, part-identification, express-van

I have a 2005 Chevrolet Express 3500 (cut-away converted into a shuttle-bus) which I've stripped bare and slowly doing a mini "schoolie" RV conversion.
While changing the spark plugs today, I noticed a pair of wires dangling loose close to the exhaust manifold on the front-left corner of the engine.
They look like they're supposed to connect to the thing (sensor?) nearby, but it's an absolute PITA to get at to take a close look (without dropping the engine out the bottom of the vehicle).
I'd like to buy a new connector to replace the broken remnants on the end of the wires, but not knowing what the thing is which they connect to, I'm stumped for being able to search for the replacement.
Can anyone help me to identify this thing which those wires connect to?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should be the coolant temperature sensor and wires. I can't tell exactly where it is in relationship to the head/exhaust, but if it is the temp sensor, it will be located to the upper left portion of the head on the flat spot where the exhaust attaches and below the valve cover. There should be two wires. It appears the boot section (female portion of the sensor) has been broken off from the sensor itself.

Comment: TYVM - now that I know what I'm looking for, this is definitely the temperature sensor, and I've also found some of the remnants of the boot. Looks like I'll be ordering a new sensor too.